# Best mathematical object to describe speed

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, dirac-delta

Suppose we want to describe speed of a particle, moving between two points on a real line:

---------------$0$----------------$1$-----------------

- If the particle starts at $0$ at $t=0$ and moves left, its speed is negative.
- If particle is constantly in 0, its speed is zero.
- If the particle starts at $0$ at $t=0$ and moves right, its speed is positive.
- If particle is simultaneously at $t=0$ seen in both $0$ and $1$, its speed is infinite.
- If particle starts at $1$ at negative time and moves left, reaching $0$ at $t=0$ its speed $\gt \infty$.

I wonder, whether non-standard numbers, such as hyperreal numbers would be appropriate here?

Comment: I doubt that nonstandard numbers or hyperreal numbers are relevant.

Comment: What makes you say *"If particle starts at $1$ at negative time and moves left, reaching $0$ at $t=0$ its speed $\gt \infty$"*?

Comment: @dmckee because it reached the destination before the origin. The target exploded before we fired. What's the projectile's speed?

Comment: You seem to be wanting the position marked $0$ to be privileged in the definition of speed here. Why shouldn't the motion be understood to have started from $1$ (after all, the object was at $1$ before it was at $0$)?

Comment: @dmckee it depends on what is the cause. We can assume the cause (cannon shot) to happen at t=0 x=0 and look where and when the explosion happened.

Comment: @dmckee For example, if the shot and the explosion happened simultaniously, the speed depends on where is the shot. If the shot is in 0, then the speed is $\infty$, if in 1, then the speed is $-\infty$.

Comment: So you want to privilege one event. Fine. Formally you can still compute the speed in the usual way $\Delta x/\Delta t = (x_{effect} - x_{cause})/(t_{effect} - t_{cause}) = (1 - 0)/((-1) - 0) = -1$. The oddity isn't that the speed is strange, but that causality between these two events runs "backward".

Comment: @dmckee your formula does not take into account what is cause and what is effect. You got -1 even for the case where the explosion happened before the shot as if the explosion were the cause.

Comment: @dmckee Here is asmall table of what do I mean (assuming $t_1$ is always zero and the cause is in x=0, t=0): $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x_1 & x_2 & t_2 & v \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \omega  \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & \omega +1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \omega  \\
 2 & 1 & -1 & 2 \omega +1 \\
 0 & 1 & -\omega  & 2 \omega  \\
 0 & \omega  & 1 & \omega  \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -\omega  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119332/2451

Answer (score 1):

To respond to the item *If particle is simultaneously at t=0  seen in both 0  and 1 , its speed is infinite*, what you seem to be describing is a particle whose position as a function of time is given by the Heaviside function. Then in the terminology of the physicists its velocity is given by the Dirac delta function. The hyperreals are indeed useful in providing a mathematical formalisation of both the Heaviside function and the Dirac delta; see for example [this recent article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-012-9289-4).